# What is difference between domain driven design and high level design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

Can anyone explain the difference between a domain driven design and High level design.

I want simple explanation of domain driven design and high level design

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you looking for definitions or comparison?

Comment: I am looking for comparison

Comment: From what perspectives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Domain Driven Design refers to the process of modelling entities (abstractions/components) in your code-base such that they make sense in your business domain. It's more like a code-design process which aims to create an evolvable backbone on which developers can build features on top.

High-Level design refers to a top level view of a system (component-level), like how webservers interact with app-servers, databases, messaging systems, etc. Also, what kind of data is transferred between those components, what protocols, etc. This type of design is more oriented to the infrastructure-level of the system, as well as data modelling.